# Drupada asking for son kill Bhishma

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma, shikhandi

In [this](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05191.htm) translation of Mahabharata, it says Drupada wanted distruction of Bhishma and hence asked for son from Shiva.

> king Drupada, O monarch, paid his adoration to the god Sankara for the sake of offspring, resolving in his mind to compass my destruction and practising the austerest of penances. And he begged Mahadeva, saying, 'Let a son, and not a daughter, be born unto me. I desire, O god, a son for revenging myself upon Bhishma.'

Why did Draupada wanted to end Bhishma? What was the cause of the hatred between them?

Comment: May be Bishma and Drona are friends one cannot take Drona and be happy, Bishma would come to take the revenge..

Comment: I don't know the sequence of events but That couldn't be the reason. After his loss to Drona,  he asked for child to end Drona and got Dristadyumna. So, this event of Shikandini birth looks like we'll before Drona's event (which happened after Pandavas defeated Drupada).

Comment: As what I heard from different madhva discourses amba did penance to siva to kill bishma but lord shiva gave her a blue flower Garland which never and tells amba that whosoever wears thy Garland will kill bishma in the mean time drupada does penance to shiva to beget make child I stead shiva said that a female child will be born later it will turn to male

Comment: Amba goes to salva prince and request him to wear the garland and kill bhisma.. for which salva denies out of fear of bhisma, amba asks many prince to wear the garland to to take out bhisma nobody dares to accept the challenge out of fear of bhisma, she ask drupada finally, even drupada denies out of fear of bhisma, later Amba disheartened puts the garland at the gate of drupada palace. She dies by suicide. The Gaurds of palace saw the unique garland which  never withers and brought it back to drupada. Amba was born as shikandini

Comment: Shikandini know about previous birth and tells to droupada that she will slay bhisma. it was the same garland given to draupadi to marry Arjuna. Arjuna wore the blude garland. it resulted in helping shikandini to slay bhisma..

Comment: All that may be true. But question was what was Drupada's hatred towards Bhishma... Why he request a son who would kill Bhishma.

Comment: why was a great man like bhishma was caused to be slain by that wretched SHikandi? Fie on SHikandi , fie on drupada